# How to run scipy's ndimage.generic_filter() faster using parallel programming?

Tags: python, scipy

scipy generic_filter can be very slow when it is applied to a large N  dimensional array. I am wondering if it can be parallelized using multiple cores since the filtering of each moving window is independent process.

Comment: Everything is possible if you follow your dreams. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Thanks! I found my answer. Should I post it here?

Comment: Tough question, it really depends on the solution. You would likely need to improve the question, too.

Comment: Please provide your suggestions. I really think it is a clear question.

Comment: _I really think it is a clear question._ I didn't say it's unclear, it's just quite broad, no?

Comment: generic_filter() is a very useful function. but also can be very slow. Multiple cores (CPUs) can be use to make it very efficient.  in this github page they were compairing the speed of different methods: https://github.com/seg/tutorials-2015/blob/master/1512_Semblance_coherence_and_discontinuity/Discontinuity_tutorial.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a function that makes the generic_filter in parallel using the multiprocessing library. It divides the big array in blocks in the rows direction and makes each block in parallel.

```
def generic_filter_parallel(in_array,num_arrays,function_generic_filter,size):
    """
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    in_array : 2D numpy array
    num_arrays : int
        number of arrays into which the big array will be spllited
    function_generic_filter : function
        function to use in the generic filter
    size : tupple
        size of the filter

    Returns
    -------
    filter_array : 2D numpy array
        array filtered


    """

    #get size for each dimension
    window_size_rows = size[0]
    window_size_cols = size[1]

    ##split arrays
    array_split = np.array_split(in_array, num_arrays)

    # generate a list of nrows as it can be different depending on how you split the array
    nrows = []
    for i_array in array_split:
        nrows.append(i_array.shape[0])

    # add borders in the upper and lower part of each spliited array
    list_split_arrays = []
    for n_array in range(num_arrays):
        if n_array == 0:
            aux = np.vstack((array_split[n_array], array_split[n_array + 1][0:window_size_rows, :]))
            list_split_arrays.append(aux)
        elif n_array < num_arrays - 1:
            aux = np.vstack((array_split[n_array - 1][-window_size_rows::, :], array_split[n_array], array_split[n_array + 1][0:window_size_rows, :]))
            list_split_arrays.append(aux)
        else:
            aux = np.vstack((array_split[n_array - 1][-window_size_rows::, :], array_split[n_array]))
            list_split_arrays.append(aux)

    #process in parallel each splitted array individually
    pool = Pool(processes=num_arrays)
    res_pool = pool.imap(partial(ndimage.generic_filter, function=function_generic_filter, size=(window_size_rows, window_size_cols)), list_split_arrays)
    pool.close()

    #collect the results
    list_filters_parallel = []
    for i in res_pool:
        list_filters_parallel.append(i)


    #compose the final image with each individual splitted array done in parallel
    filter_array = np.zeros(in_array.shape)
    ini_row = 0
    fin_row = 0
    for n_array in range(num_arrays):

        if n_array == 0:
            ini_row = 0
            fin_row = nrows[n_array]
        else:
            ini_row = ini_row + nrows[n_array - 1]
            fin_row = fin_row + nrows[n_array]

        if n_array == 0:
            aux = list_filters_parallel[n_array][ini_row:fin_row, :]
            filter_array[ini_row:fin_row, :] = aux
        elif n_array < num_arrays - 1:
            aux = list_filters_parallel[n_array][window_size_rows:-window_size_rows, :]
            filter_array[ini_row:fin_row, :] = aux
        else:
            aux = list_filters_parallel[n_array][window_size_rows::, :]
            filter_array[ini_row:fin_row, :] = aux


    return filter_array
```

Comment: Thank you. It is similar to what I ended up doing: https://github.com/BehrangK/parallel-generic_filter.  I used joblib.

Comment: Thanks @Behrang for your code. By the way, depending on the function you want to use (for example one built-in function from numpy) maybe it is intersting to use skimage.util.view_as_windows to get crops of your input array and make the operation using matrix operations.